# How to Start an each() Loop When it Ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I use `each()` function in jQuery for some operations :

```
$("div img").each(function(){
    //loop count = count of img tags
});
```

And how i can start this `each()` loop again when it ends?
I want to recall this event automatically when the iterations completed.
Also i don't want to use `setTimeOut()`.

Thank in Advanced.

Comment: i... don't understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: i'm quite sure if you tell us what you are looking for, someone will find a better workaround than freezing the UI

Comment: If you just want to count img tags, you don't need to loop at all

Comment: write a function with your code and recall in the last line of the function.

Comment: no, i want recall each() when it's completed

Comment: You want an infinite loop?

Comment: @saman gholami can you tell us what exactlly what you want to do? you have to show us some code otherwise it will be very difficult to tell you something

Comment: Okay, but why? To do what?

Comment: mi answer solved your infinite loop : D

Comment: Yes , the infinite loop.

Comment: @samangholami an infinite loop will create a stack error and then your application will crash... What do you want to achieve with an infinite loop?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon for an image slider for example

Comment: You need a) an interval or b) an `.animate()` callback.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon could you write an example please?

Comment: Based on your comment on one of the answers below, this won't do what you want it to do. Try asking another question with what you are trying to achieve and see if you can get some more relevant help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the infinite loop you asked for.

```
function loop() {
    $("div img").each(function(){
        //loop count = count of img tags
    });

   loop();
}

loop();
```

Update as OP request: using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) :/

```
function loop() {
    $("div img").each(function(){
        //loop count = count of img tags
    });
}

var intervalID = window.setInterval(loop, 500);
```

Comment: Thank you, is it execute async?

Comment: @saman: No. For that you would have to use `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, but you explicitly said you don't want to use it.

Comment: Yes, i think i should use setInterval for this operation,thank you...please update your answer with this solution and i select your answer as best :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just put it in a for loop, it will execute after each other.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    $("div img").each(function(){
        //loop count = count of img tags
    });
}
```

This will loop through it twice.

Comment: Thanks for Answer, if i want loop through it ever what should i do?and is this solution async?i mean the for loop MUST ends then the codes after for executed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will only run after the first one has ended. Just test it out, you will see. It is not async, but why do you want that?

Comment: for example,an image slider.when all of images show, start againg from first image.and another codes execute along side.